# Modules that can be safely disabled that require 3rd party subscriptions

Tags: magento2.3.1

I'm just working my way through the latest update of 2.3.1. And as usual, I'm seeing some pre-installed modules that require subscriptions to 3rd party services in order to actually use them.

Such as (not sure if I missed any):

- **Engagement Cloud:** `dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension`
- **New Relic Reporting:** `magento/module-new-relic-reporting`
- **Signfyd:** `magento/module-signifyd`
- **Temando Shipping:** `temando/module-shipping-m2`
- **Vertex:** `vertex/module-tax`

I've done some initial checks such as:

1. Verify no circular dependencies: `bin/magento info:dependencies:show-modules-circular`
2. Disabling each module without seeing a dependency error message

But would like to know if anyone has run into any issues **further down the line** after disabling them.

Comment: Although not directly related to specifically 3rd party modules, Integar have done a nice article on removing unused modules in general (https://www.integer-net.com/make-magento-2-small-again/). 4/5 modules you mentioned are in there. I'm running a few production sites with no issues at all disabling these.